# Determine if the type of an object matches a nested type defined via the typing module

Tags: python, python-typing

With the **typing** module, it's possible to specify arbitrary nested types, like `List[str]` or `Dict[str, Dict[str, float]]`. Is there a way to determine whether the type of an object matches such a type? Something along the lines of

```
>>> from typing import List
>>> isinstance(['a', 'b'], List[str])
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "/home/cbieganek/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 1162, in __instancecheck__
#     return issubclass(instance.__class__, self)
#   File "/home/cbieganek/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 1148, in __subclasscheck__
#     raise TypeError("Parameterized generics cannot be used with class "
# TypeError: Parameterized generics cannot be used with class or instance checks
```

I didn't really expect `isinstance()` to work for this, but I'm wondering if there is some other accepted way of doing this.

Comment: No, they are type hints. Third-party static time type checkers may provide a way to do this, but note, that is based on the types you've annotated. If you want a runtime check, you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics appeared in python as a part of type [hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). So convenient way to use *List[str]* is a type hint for variable or function parameter:

```
my_list: List[str] = ['1', '2']
```

or

```
def do_something(strings: List[str])->None:
    ...
```

Most modern IDEs like PyCharm or Athom has plugins which are support static type check for python code, also look at [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/). If strict run time type check is necessary, it's possible to iterate over list and check each item type, but it is not a good design.